Google site verification does not see google-site-verification tag
For a site, I wanted to add <meta name="robots" content="noindex"> and have Google index this tag.
For that I went to the site verification tool and added <meta name="google-site-verification" content="oG7LHEogE-io38I1jQ3LQN_6SWqy6TAHu-RTCcB68RI" /> as you can see on https://developer-dev.enecogroup.com/ . However, the site verification tool keeps indicating that the tag is not there, while it is clearly visible when using the developer tools.
What am I doing wrong?
The output after trying to verify is (translated from Dutch);

Verification method: HTML tag
Cause of error: We couldn't find your
verification meta tag.

edit; added a screenshot of what I see in the dev tools of Chrome;


"as you can see on https://developer-dev.enecogroup.com/" - no, I can't. The source code my browser shows me for that URL, does not contain the text content google-site-verification anywhere.

The DOM contains that element, but the initial source code received from the server, doesn't. Google site verification probably only checks on the former, and doesn't actually "execute" the page.

thank you for checking! When I use the developer tools of Chrome and check the page it shows the tags. Is there another way to check this?

Chrome dev tools, element view, shows you the DOM. You need to use right click on some "blank" area of the document, and then "show page source" (or similar), to see the actual HTML the server returned for the requested URL; or inspect the request in the network panel.

Ok, first of if we inspect the code send by server there is no google-site-verification meta in the header. I don't know what framework/technology you are using to render your site (seems like Angular), but what you need is to render your HTML on server, which you doesn't. I assume you are checking presence of tag in browser "inspect" tool, which is updating live which mean it track javascript changes. If you go to: view-source:https://developer-dev.enecogroup.com/ (chrome) there is no google site verification token. Despite all talk by Google they still struggle to render SPA properly by all tools, so I would recommend to either insert this in server html element or add token as a DNS record https://support.google.com/a/answer/183895?hl=en

I think you done it, but just to make sure: The verification meta tag needs to be placed within the <head> section.

thank you for checking, as far as I can see, that's where the tag is?

@GuyHagemans did you tried getting a new verification code?
